# How to parse list using shell and update set of yaml files

Tags: shell, yaml

I have a list of values in a text file like so:

```
service-1 | a /
service-1 | b /path2/
service-2 | b /path3/
service-2 | b /path4/
```

I also have a YAML for each of the services like `service-1.yaml`, `service-2.yaml`, etc. Each one has an ingress path where I need to put the path:

```
ingress: 
  instances: 
    - auth: a
      path: 
        <to be filled in>
        <to be filled in>
    - auth: b
      path: 
        <to be filled in>
        <to be filled in>
```

I want to parse the text file in Shell and then update the appropriate fields in the YAML. I know I can parse the first and second parts using cut, e.g.,

`echo "service-1 | a /" | cut -d "|" -f1` or `echo "service-1 | a /" | cut -d "|" -f2`, but how can I determine which service is which and which paths go where in the YAML? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the YAML processor [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) to solve this task.
The following code shows a solution for just *one* file.
You can put it in a bash loop that iterates over all files.

```bash
SERVICE='service-1'   # or 'service-2'
PATHS='servicePaths.txt'
FILE_IN="$SERVICE.yaml"
FILE_OUT="$SERVICE.out.yaml"

yq -y --arg service $SERVICE --rawfile paths $PATHS '
def getPath($auth):
  $paths / "\n"                                         # split lines by "\n"
  | map(. / "|"                                         # split each line by "|"
        | map(sub("^\\s+";"") | sub("\\s+$";""))        # trim strings
        | select(any)                                   # remove empty array (empty lines in file servicePaths.txt)
        | [.[0], (.[1] / " " | .[0], .[1])]             # split auth/path by " "
        | select(.[0] == $service and .[1] == $auth))   # keep only definitions where $service and $auth match
  | .[0][2] // "path undefined";                        # return path of first match or default if no match found

.ingress.instances |= map(.path = getPath(.auth))' "$FILE_IN" > "$FILE_OUT"
```

**File `service-1.out.yaml`**

```yaml
ingress:
  instances:
    - auth: a
      path: /
    - auth: b
      path: /path2/
```

**File `service-2.out.yaml`**

```yaml
ingress:
  instances:
    - auth: a
      path: path undefined
    - auth: b
      path: /path3/
```

**Remarks**

- `yq` offers an option `-i` for inplace editing of files, if you want to replace the original template file instead of using $FILE_OUT.
- the function `getPath($auth)` builds up a lookup for the paths from the file `servicePaths.txt` and then selects the correct path for `$service` and `$auth`
- `.ingress.instances |= map(...)` in the last line updates the paths of all services (`|=` is the update operator)
- the solution is fail safe:

  - if no path for `service, auth` is defined in `servicePaths.txt` then `"path undefined"` is inserted.
  - if more than one path is defined, the first path from `servicePaths.txt` is inserted.

**Variation**

If it is valid to have multiple definitions of paths for the same service/auth, use this little modification:

```bash
SERVICE='service-1'   # or 'service-2'
PATHS='servicePaths.txt'
FILE_IN="$SERVICE.yaml"
FILE_OUT="$SERVICE.out.yaml"

yq -y --arg service $SERVICE --rawfile paths $PATHS '
def getPath($auth):
  $paths / "\n"                                         # split lines by "\n"
  | map(. / "|"                                         # split each line by "|"
        | map(sub("^\\s+";"") | sub("\\s+$";""))        # trim strings
        | select(any)                                   # remove empty array (empty lines in file servicePaths.txt)
        | [.[0], (.[1] / " " | .[0], .[1])]             # split auth/path by " "
        | select(.[0] == $service and .[1] == $auth))   # keep only definitions where $service and $auth match
  | map(.[2]);                                          # return paths of all matches

.ingress.instances |= map(.path = getPath(.auth))' "$FILE_IN" > "$FILE_OUT"
```

**File `service-1.out.yaml`**

```yaml
ingress:
  instances:
    - auth: a
      path:
        - /
    - auth: b
      path:
        - /path2/
```

**File `service-2.out.yaml`**

```yaml
ingress:
  instances:
    - auth: a
      path: []
    - auth: b
      path:
        - /path3/
        - /path4/
```

Comment: @jspeng Thank you! Is this with a specific version of yq? I am trying with v4 in my local and `-y` and `--arg` flags are not found.

Comment: I linked the used [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) above. The syntax is similar, but not identical. Each version has its advantages. In this case in [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) you cannot define own functions.

Comment: @jspeng is there any special configuration needed for jq? I installed kislyuk/yq using `brew install python-yq` which also installed jq, but I am seeing a new error for line 1: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): null (null) and string (" ") cannot be divided`

Comment: `jq-1.6` and `yq-3.10`